# CSS HTML page numbering

Tags: html, css, printing

I know this question has been asked. However I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. I want page numbers to be printed on the top-right of the page when printing an html.

This is the code I have, what is wrong?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style media="print">
    @page {
        counter-increment: page;
        counter-reset: page 1;
        @top-right {
            content: "Page " counter(page) " of " counter(pages);
        }
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div style="height:800px">hello</div>
    <div style="height:800px">hello</div>
    <div style="height:800px">hello</div>
    <div style="height:800px">hello</div>
    <div style="height:800px">hello</div>
    <div style="height:800px">hello</div>
    <div style="height:800px">hello</div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is specific to the browser you're attempting to use this CSS rule with.  The `@top-right` CSS at-rule looks like it's supported by IE8, but no other browsers.

Check out `@Page` margin boxes for some more information about this.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use @page for any of that except, perhaps, as @alex pointed out. [According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@page)

> You can only change the margins, orphans, widows, and page breaks of
>   the document. Attempts to change any other CSS properties will be
>   ignored.